# SLES 12 syntax error: '=~' unexpected operator/operand

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

i have developed a bigger script for SLES11 and everything is running fine.
But with SLES12 there are some syntax errors when starting the script.

ERROR: `syntax error: '=~' unexpected operator/operand`

```
#!/bin/ksh

while [[ ! $BIGTAB =~ ^-?[0-9* ]+$ ]] || [[ ! $BIGTAB -ge 1 ]]; do
echo "  Enter number of tables to display:"
read BIGTAB
...
```

`=~` seems to be not supported any more!?
Could you give me help, how to replace the syntax for SLES12 (and still also running under SLES11).

Thank you!

Comment: check the ksh version on your SLES 12.

Comment: SLES11: Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01
SLES12: LEGACY KSH R50 2015/04/19 SLES

Comment: If you can't get ksh93 for SLES12, I'd suggest switching to bash -- while the syntax isn't always identical, modern versions are quite feature-complete, providing even some of the more obscure features such as namevars. (Floating-point math is still missing, but that's easy 'nuff to work around).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [legacy ksh](https://www.mirbsd.org/htman/i386/man1/lksh.htm) (built on mksh) on SLES 12:

```
# echo $KSH_VERSION
@(#)LEGACY KSH R54 2016/11/11
# [[ a =~ a ]]
ksh: syntax error: '=~' unexpected operator/operand
#
```

So you need to install the *real* ksh/ksh93 (not sure what's the pkg name on SLES though).

```
# echo $KSH_VERSION
Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01
# [[ a =~ a ]]
#
```

#### UPDATE:

Just checked SUSE's web site, there's ksh (and no mksh) in [SLES 11](https://www.suse.com/LinuxPackages/packageRouter.jsp?product=server&version=11&service_pack=&architecture=x86_64&package_name=index_all) but only mksh in [SLES 12](https://www.suse.com/LinuxPackages/packageRouter.jsp?product=server&version=12&service_pack=&architecture=x86_64&package_name=index_all).

#### UPDATE #2:

According to the SLES 12 SP1 [release notes](https://www.suse.com/releasenotes/x86_64/SUSE-SLES/12-SP1/), you need to install the [legacy module](https://www.suse.com/products/server/features/modules/) to get back ksh.

> 1.4.1.3 Support for Korn Shell (ksh) Extended Until End of March 2022
>
> Support for the ***legacy package*** ksh in SLE was originally slated to end in 2017. However, many customers still depend on ksh.
>
> Support for ksh has been extended until the end of March 2022.
>
> Beyond that time, you can use the mksh implementation of Korn Shell (package mksh). However, as mksh is based on pdksh, there are certain functional differences. For example, its handling of pipelines is similar to Bash.
>
> 8.2.5 KSH 93v Replaced with KSH 93u Report
>
> In the ***Legacy Module*** for SUSE Linux Enterprise 12, we shipped KSH 93v. However, the 93v branch was not fully stable yet.
>
> With SLE 12 SP1, we release KSH 93u, which is more stable version 93v. In order to provide a regular update path from 93v to 93u, a higher version number (93vu) has been used for this update.

Comment: ran into this same issue (SLES 12 dropped spt for ksh93) a few months back; had so many problems with broken links and missing libs that I said fuqit and installed `ksh-93vu-13.1.x86_64.rpm` from [RPM resource for ksh93](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=ksh93&submit=Search+...&system=&arch=), updated the links in `/bin` and `/usr/bin` and haven't looked back; perhaps the latest/gretest patches (SLES 12) will finally work ... shrug

Answer (score -1):

I don't have SLES12 to test it, but it seems your problem is not the `=~` operator, but your operand (it has one space in the middle of the regular expression).

Try this:

```
[[ ! $BIGTAB =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]
```

Comment: Hi, the "*" and the "space" is there, because it should be possible to enter these characters, too (instead of a number). Its a special input field :-)
The error still occurs ...

Comment: `[[ ]]` has its own parsing rules, so this value isn't subject to being split into substrings (when the space is part of a character class definition) as would otherwise be the case.

Comment: Which is to say -- if you have real ksh93 handy (it's shipped with MacOS, for example), the following doesn't provide any syntax error: `ksh -c ' [[ ! $BIGTAB =~ ^-?[0-9* ]+$ ]] '`